# Webpack bundles and source React files after deployment

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following query. When deploying a React app, what is being deployed is the .js and .css bundles produced By Webpack. However, by using Chrome dev tools under Sources tab, I am able to see all the source code - every single file being used during development. So, the question is `how is that possible and who is responsible for that`?

Moreover, it seems Chrome debugger has some issues with these source files e.g. skips lines when debugging using F10, cannot recognize some variables in watch window etc. At the same time, everything works fine locally during development. I suspect the second question has to do with the first one. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack uses plugins which "map" your JS for the devtools, you can read more about it [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/).